# Getting table metadata in MySQL

Tags: mysql, syntax, constraints

I'm trying to find out how to get the following constraint information from a table in MySQL 5.0:

- primary key
- foreign keys and table references
- unique columns

What is the syntax of the query or queries to do so? I have a feeling I'm close with [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/table-constraints-table.html), but there is no example.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [SHOW COLUMNS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-columns.html) command will show you the primary key and unique columns for a table.

As for foreign keys, you **could** use something like the [SHOW CREATE TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-create-table.html) command which will output the DDL statements needed to replicate the table.

Comment: SHOW COLUMNS doesn't show the UNIQUE restraint from what I can tell (just primary and foreign keys), but I can use SHOW CREATE TABLE if I have to. I was just looking for a way to specifically isolate the constraints without returning other information.

Comment: Check the link I posted. Under the subheading detailing the "key" column it says that it can be either "PRI", "UNI", "MUL" or empty. "UNI" indicates a unique field.

Comment: You could "SELECT CONSTRAINT_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'foo'" or something like that?

Comment: @fluffels - When I run SHOW COLUMNS FROM table_name, or SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM table_name, it will show the PRI and MUL, but I can't seem to get it to display UNI. I had also been thinking that MUL meant the foreign key, but I was mistaken in that regard.

Comment: That's odd. Does the unique show up when you query the DDL? Perhaps something changed that attribute?

Comment: It shows up when I use the SHOW CREATE TABLE command, but not SHOW COLUMNS. Your other query just showed a table with the values PRIMARY KEY and UNIQUE, but no column names.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I think I'm going to use the SHOW CREATE TABLE command because it has everything I need, I'll just need to parse it a little.

Comment: Actually, I was able to do it all with SHOW INDEX, but it makes an assumption that foreign keys will not also be marked with the unique constraint. Is that a safe assumption?

Comment: @VirtuosiMedia: I think that's a good assumption, because I see no reason why a foreign key would be marked unique. In that case, two related entities would be same, no?

Comment: To clarify, unique foreign keys would indicate a 1:1 mapping, in which I don't see much sense.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I figured as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 31):

For MySQL:

**1) get Table/Fields metadata**

```
SELECT table_schema, table_name, column_name, ordinal_position, data_type, 
       numeric_precision, column_type, column_default, is_nullable, column_comment 
  FROM information_schema.columns 
  WHERE (table_schema='schema_name' and table_name = 'table_name')
  order by ordinal_position;
```

**OR**

```
show fields from 'table_name'
```

---

**2) get Foregn Keys referenced table**

```
SELECT `REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME` 
   FROM `information_schema`.`KEY_COLUMN_USAGE`
   WHERE
       `TABLE_NAME` = 'table_name' AND
       `COLUMN_NAME` = 'Column_Name'
```

**3) get indexes (primary and foreign) for a table**

```
show keys from `table_name`
```

---

**5) get All indexes and referreced table**

```
SELECT *
  FROM `KEY_COLUMN_USAGE`
  WHERE
      `TABLE_NAME` = 'table_name' AND
      `TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'schema_name'
```

**OR**

```
SELECT *
  FROM `REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS`
  WHERE
      `TABLE_NAME` = 'table_name' AND
      `CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA` = 'schema_name'
```

---

**6) get STORED PROCEDURES**

```
SELECT * 
  FROM `ROUTINES`
  WHERE
     `ROUTINE_SCHEMA` = 'schema_name'
```

---

**7) get TRIGGERS**

```
SELECT * 
  FROM `TRIGGERS`
  WHERE 
     `TRIGGER_SCHEMA` = 'schema_name'
```

---

**8) get EVENTS**

```
SELECT * 
  FROM `EVENTS`
  WHERE 
     `EVENT_SCHEMA` = 'schema_name'
```

---

**9) get VIEWS**

```
SELECT *
  FROM `VIEWS`
  WHERE
      `TABLE_NAME` = 'table_name' AND
      `TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'schema_name'
```

Answer (score 9):

Use

```
 show fields from table_name
 show keys from table_name
```

to get primary keys, foreign keys, unique, etc.

to get the table referenced by a foreign key use:

```
 SELECT `REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME` 
 FROM `information_schema`.`KEY_COLUMN_USAGE` 
 WHERE 
     `TABLE_NAME` = '[table_containing_foreign_key]' AND 
     `COLUMN_NAME` = '[foreign_key]'
```

substituting `[table_containing_foreign_key]` and `[foreign_key]` with your values

Answer (score 3):

use the following to get the same using Select Query:

```
SELECT table_schema, table_name, column_name, ordinal_position, data_type, numeric_precision, column_type FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = '[TABLE_NAME]';
```

Answer (score 2):

You should try it and see. INFORMATION_SCHEMA is part of some standard and is supported in a (mostly) similar way in other databases; this standard should be documented - you can look for that doc.

But mainly the way would be to create a bunch of test tables, and then have a look at INFORMATION_SCHEMA to see what's there.

Comment: The problem is that there is no example query syntax, though. That's all I really need. Other sections in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA chapter have syntax examples, but this one doesn't.

Comment: @MarkR: You might like to refer to this: http://www.xcdsql.org/MySQL/information_schema/5.1/MySQL_5_1_INFORMATION_SCHEMA.html