# Getting metadata in a table MySQL

Tags: mysql, metadata

I need to write a query to get the metadata in a specific table and I have no idea what to do. I don't really understand what to do.

Comment: Can you provide us with more details? What Metadata for example, and I'm not quite sure if you want to insert or select the data itself.

Comment: Googling `Getting metadata in a table MySQL`  gives me plenty of good results, eg. [Getting table metadata in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/q/510410)

Comment: @Janne Kyckling - Please tell me what metadata you want?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure what metadata I'm looking for; it's not specified in the description. It just says that I should find the metadata in one of my tables and tables who are related to that one.

Comment: use [mydbname]
go
SELECT * 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_NAME= 'mytblname';
go

Comment: Something like that should work but it doesn't show any information.

Comment: Too harsh I think.  It's a very short question, but I have the same one and this answers it (thanks google).  @JanneKyckling, you will stop getting down votes if you edit the question and get a bit more specific.

Answer (score 6):

Use following query to get metadata of your table

```
select * from information_schema.tables
 where table_schema='your_database_name' and table_name='your_table_name';
```

It will provide table_type,engine,version,row_format,table_rows,avg_row_length etc

Comment: Thanks, but I already used that code and I don't get any information. But when I change information_schema.tables to information_schema.COLUMNS it seems to work. Now I have to do the same with tables that are related to the main one and I am once again lost. I don't know which tables are related, how do you see that.

Comment: @JanneKyckling - dear friend first of all you have to decide what are the things you need in your result. Then only we can provide correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

The metadata information regarding a table is spread across few tables in INFORMATION_SCHEMA database.

The table: schemata holds the information related to the databases
The table: tables holds informations related to the tables in the databases
The table: columns holds informations related to columns in the tables

If you cannot read information_schema with the current mysql user, then the following simple queries can help you as well: `show create table xx` (this will return one single record as a resultset, which you have to parse - not very easy to do) or `desc xx` (this will return the columns from the specified table, along with informations about them - column names, data type, null/not null, information about keys, information about default value).