# Search entire table for a keyword

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a trivial question. Im using PHP+MySQL managing a huge DB

I want to search in a entire table a keyword I write in a input.

The problem is that the main table have +100 columns, so I had to write the php query manually

```
[...]
$sql="select * 
from db 
where ID LIKE '%".$q."%' or USER_ID LIKE '%".$q."%' or Phone_ID LIKE '%".$q."%' or
Fax_ID LIKE '%".$q."%' or email_ID LIKE '%".$q."%' or [...]
```

And this is a chaos when I modify a column, or add/remove...

Exist any other way to make this search? If not, I tought about create a separate PHP function, that obtains all column header names, and create an auto-fill function inside.

I tried to look for info with no success
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=search+entire+table

Comment: What kind of database table has over a hundred columns...?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol you know it's going to be bad when it's referred to as "the main table".

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I join the main details in this table. It was not useful have different tables, so the correlation is 1:1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there isnt any simple way to do this.

One option is to select all columns in table, fetch them as array and iterate over them and build your WHERE clause.

```
select column_name from information_schema.columns
where table_name = 'TableName'
```

This will make whole script slower, if you want to go this way i would recommend you to use some caching.

Comment: Maybe this is the best answer we can afford now. Hope to write the function and integrate your idea. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could get the column info for the 'main table'  using info from the *information schema*. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510410/getting-table-metadata-in-mysql) are some methods for using MySQL. [Here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.metadata.php) is how to do it using PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a [SHOW COLUMNS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-columns.html) on the table, then loop over the `Field` to get all the column names in the table, at least that way you don't have a hand-coded mess to deal with.