# Failed to execute "SHOW CREATE TABLE" query in Qt

Tags: c++, mysql, qt

Suppose I have a table called 'logs' in mysql and I want to get the create query of this table in Qt(5.2 mingw). 
Here is what I have done so far:

```
QSqlQuery query(connection);

query.prepare("SHOW CREATE TABLE logs");
if(query.exec())
{
    if(query.next())
        query.value(1).toString();
}
```

After executing the code, the query.exec() returns true but the query.next() returns false.
This query executes successfully in the mysql client(navicat) so I'm pretty sure about the query.

Note that QSqlQuery::lastError() gives -1 means no error!

I'll appreciate for any guidance or help.

Comment: Shouldn't it be query.value(0); ?

Comment: @DieterLücking: his issue is next, not value.

Comment: Actually it doesn't matter since query.next() returns false!

Comment: @Mosi, are you sure it is ok to get the next in a freshly created table?

Comment: @LaszloPapp: The table is already created, I'm getting the query which creates the table.

Comment: You create an empty table, so what sense does next do?

Comment: I'm not creating an empty table. It has to return table name and create sql statement. What I suppose to do to get the create statement?

Comment: `next()` returns false because `next()` [only works when the query is a select](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qsqlquery.html#next). In sqlite you could do a select on the sqlite_master table, I don't know the equivalent for mysql. [Perhaps this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/510410/getting-table-metadata-in-mysql)

Comment: @Mosi: you get the create statement, but what next would do for it? It only makes sense if you have a table you wish to select from as others already wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`query.next()` is only appropriate when executing a `SELECT` statement. It has no meaning for any other SQL statement.

Comment: thanks and solve it this way:CREATE TABLE t1 LIKE t2